# How to get the output on this PHP script?

Tags: php

I'm a newbie to programming and PHP learning about two dimensional arrays.

When I run this code below, it just gives me a blank page. When I put an echo in front of the function call like this `echo usort($a, 'mysort1');`  the page shows me a 1 (I have no idea why).

**What I really want to see is the output of the array after it's been sorted.**

Doing `var_dump($a);` is not what I'm after. how do I show the result of the function?

How? Thanks if you can help.

```
<?php

$a = array (
array ('key1' => 940, 'key2' => 'blah'),
array ('key1' => 23, 'key2' => 'this'),
array ('key1' => 894, 'key2' => 'that')
);


function mysort1($x, $x) {
     return ($x['key1'] > $y['key']);

}

usort($a, 'mysort1'); 


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters I think you have two typos in your comparison function:

```
                     //should be $y not $x
function mysort1($x, $y) {
     return ($x['key1'] > $y['key1']);  // Should be $y['key1']
}
```

Next, usort sorts the array in place returning TRUE on success and FALSE otherwise, that is why you see a 1 when you echo it's return value.

Try:

```
print_r($a);
```

to display the sorted array.

Answer (score 1):

Put this as the last line... var_dump($a); it is a quick way to see what is in an array.

Comment: Thanks, but what I want to see is the result of the function. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Well var_dump() will give a verbose output from the array... if you want to see individually what each value is in each array, you could use a couple for loops and print each key and value. Other than that, the usort function just returns a 1 which mean that the function completed and returned true.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
print_r($a);
```

after your usort

If you want to output the data nicely using HTML, you could use a foreach loop as follows:

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($a as $key => $value)
{
    echo "<li>key: ", $key, " value: ", $value, "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Or something similar with tables if you like.

usort actually sorts the array you pass to it. In other words, it does not return a sorted array but performs the sort on the same array you pass it because it's passing by reference. If you look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php you will see there is an ampersand infront of the parameter. The return value of usort indicates success or failure. Again, you can see this in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the return value of the [function usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) , and not the contents of your array. Instead try giving [print_r](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) a shot after calling usort.

Answer (score 0):

Add after the usort line

```
var_dump( $a );
```

Your page only prints "1" because it is saying that usort was successful in sorting the array.